# Get database statistics via GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am migrating from `database/sql` to `jinzhu/gorm` in my project. Previously, I captured my database situation with [`Stats`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Stats) method. I am wondering how can I achieve that in GORM? I found nothing in the official doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gorm` is (usually) a wrapper around `sql.DB`.

You can access the underlying `*sql.DB` object by calling [DB.DB()](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jinzhu/gorm?tab=doc#DB.DB). You then have access to any method in the standard library, including `DB.Stats()`.

Note the comment in the docs:

> DB get `*sql.DB` from current connection If the underlying database
>   connection is not a *sql.DB, returns nil

For example:

```
// db is a *gorm.DB
db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", connectionString)
...
// sqlDB is a *sql.DB
sqlDB := db.DB()
if sqlDB != nil {
  // Call to the standard library's sql.DB.Stats
  stats := sqlDB.Stats()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Gorm Doc](https://jinzhu.me/gorm/advanced.html#generic-database-interface-sqldb)

> Get generic database interface *sql.DB from *gorm.DB connection
>
> > //Get generic database object `*sql.DB` to use its functions
> >
> > db.DB()

Using `db.DB()` you can get `*sql.DB` and use function `.Stats()` where `db` is `*gorm.DB` connection

```
sqlDBStats := db.DB().Stats()
```